# ag-grid won't scroll after rendering

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

**SOLVED: turns out I was importing the incorrect CSS which causes some pretty severe issues, read answer for more details**

After implementing ag-grid, data is showing but I am unable to scroll at all.

I made a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytr1jj.
The stackblitz works as expected but, for some reason, the exact same code fails to scroll in my app.[image]

I have tried multiple ways of rendering the rows.
I have tried messing with the CSS to see if there is anything causing an overlap in the scrollbar.
[image: bar is inaccesible]

so far no luck. I think it might have something to do with "pointer events"...

**Update: I think that the virtual scroll requires the mouse event to be captured on the row, and for some reason the mouse event is not being captured and therefore can't scroll**

```
<ag-grid-angular
  #agGrid
  style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"
  class="ag-theme-balham"
  [rowData]="rowData" 
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  >
</ag-grid-angular>


columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'Make', field: 'make' },
    { headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
    { headerName: 'Price', field: 'price' }
  ];

  rowData = [
    { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
    { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 }
  ];
```

**UPDATE 2: I am able to get the scrollbar to scroll if i set `pointer-events: none` to `.ag-center-cols-viewport`. the html seems to be updating on scroll and the row-index row-id etc is updating as it scrolls, however the table view seems to not to not show the current rows being inserted into the ref="ag-center-cols-viewport" (they are appearing in the html but they are not visible)**

Answer (score 4):

**ANSWER**

okay so, this is a bit ridiculous but here it goes

```
BAD
@import "~ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
@import "~ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css";
```

```
GOOD
@import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
@import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css';
```

After checking my package.json again I noticed I had 3 things of ag-grid under dependencies

```
"ag-grid",
"ag-grid-angular",
"ag-grid-community"
```

The CSS I was importing was from the old version of `"ag-grid"`.
After removing `"ag-grid"` from package.json I imported the proper CSS and everything worked immediately...

Final Good Code

```
// package.json
    "ag-grid-angular": "^20.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^20.0.0",

// _vendor.scss where I import most my node_modules css

    // @import "~ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
    // @import "~ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css";
    @import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
    @import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-material.css';
```

Comment: your should also import ag grid parts from ag-grid-community, otherwise your bundle will contain full grid in every module you import it